# Are you allowed to pray on a floor that’s najis?

Tags: salat, najis

Are you allowed to pray on a floor that’s najis, but dry, if you are praying on a prayer mat? By dry najis I mean that there for example has been something najis such as blood that has dried up.

Comment: By dry najis do you mean like a floor which has been walked by shoes or do you mean actually there was something najis such as urine which has been dried up ? Please clarify

Comment: Just clarified did

Answer (score -2):

I am Muslim. Its depend on your head, for example for me its "Makarem Shirazi" , and he said yes you can't pray on that floor! i can give you some resources to read if you want.